# [Solved]catkin_make error: c++: error: $(catkin_LIBRARIES) no such file or directory

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good afternoon partners

I´m running ROS Groovy on Raspbian .

I wrote a publisher in C++ "robot1.cpp" .

After that and following the instructions from:

> http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

I added these lines at bottom of my CMakeLists.txt:

> include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
> > 
> > add_executable(robot1 src/robot1.cpp)
> > 
> > target_link_libraries(robot1 ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

> add_dependencies(robot1 alvaro_generate_messages_cpp)

When I do "catkin_make" I get the next :

> [ 21%] Building CXX object alvaro/CMakeFiles/robot1.dir/src/robot1.cpp.o

> /tmp/ccREQxsT.s: Assembler messages:

> /tmp/ccREQxsT.s:505: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for this architecture

> Linking CXX executable /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/alvaro/robot1

> c++: error: $(catkin_LIBRARIES):There is no such file or directory

> make[2]: *** [/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/alvaro/robot1] Error 1

> make[1]: *** [alvaro/CMakeFiles/robot1.dir/all] Error 2

> make: *** [all] Error 2

> Invoking "make" failed

I´ve just followed the tutorial steps so that I don´t know what´s happening.

Can you help me please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/145221/%5Bsolved%5Dcatkin_make-error:-c++:-error:-$(catkin_libraries)-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-03-27**:
Oh my God! I´m quite blind .... apologies for any inconvenience. I need my glasses to see ... I´m absolutely a disaster. It was exactly what you said to me. I didn´t realice it.  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} rather than $(catkin_LIBRARIES). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp ... in your CMakeLists.txt? Are your sure your CMakeLists.txt contains  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} rather than $(catkin_LIBRARIES) (suggested by your error) ?

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3